# How not to prepend package to gRPC service callout

Tags: java, grpc

I have a Node gRPC server running locally. A package is not specified in the protobuf for this service: *NodeService*

I'm trying to make a Java client for the service using Maven. In the tutorials in this you provide a package name, in this case com.example.grpc.

When I try to make a request to the server using this Java client I'm getting back

`io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: RPC method not implemented /com.example.grpc.NodeService/Login`

This makes sense as the Service is running at `/NodeService` not `/com.example.grpc.NodeService`. I've tested this with a node client(no package in protobuf) and this works.

So my question is can I flat out remove the prepending of the package to the Service name or do I have to compile the supporting files in that directory(and bonus question to point me in the direction in how to do that with `mvn package`).

Comment: The package name should be independent of the folder structure (although they should be kept in sync for sanity). Why don't you just remove the `package` definition from the .proto file? You should be able to use the same `.proto` file for both languages.

Comment: So protoc is installing the generated classes in a target directory at the top level of the project. Do I just need get those files into src/main and then I can remove the package name?

Comment: The package name in the .proto needs to stay. Is the problem that you need to define [`java_package` (and ideally `java_outer_classname`) in the .proto](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#defining-your-protocol-format)?